# Dropdown with Radio button and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I coded a dropdown menu with radio button to change currency in my website. I use jQuery to open/close this dropdown but the currency change doesn't work.

The `expanded` class is used to open/close the dropdown menu.

I think that the error comes from the line `$('#' + $(e.target).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);` but I don't know how to modify this. I want it to check the right input.

```js
$('.maincar__currency').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#' + $(e.target).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $('.maincar__currency').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.maincar__currency {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: $shadowBox;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.maincar__currency label {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  cursor: pointer;
  //box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maincar__currency label:hover {
  background-color: $extraLightGrey;
}

.currency {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.currency input {
  display: none;
}

.currency img {
  //object-fit: contain;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.currency span {
  display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  color: $mediumMainGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency">
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__euro">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/euro.png" alt="Euro sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked="true">
            <span class="default">EUR</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__dollar">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/dollar.png" alt="Dollar sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar">
            <span>USD</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__pound">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/pound-sterling.png" alt="Pound sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp">
            <span>GBP</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__chf">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/swiss-franc.png" alt="Swiss franc sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf">
            <span>CHF</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant CSS to the question. It's not clear what the issue is without it

Comment: I just edited my question with CSS code

Comment: @lf_celine it seems... You're trying to make a custom `<select><option>` - menu?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='currency-is']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
        }
    });
});
```

You'll get the radio button value. Let me know if this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

CSS (add these extra classes):

```
.maincar__currency label{
    display: none;
}
.expanded label{
    display: block;
}
```

JS & Html:

```
$('.maincar__currency').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});

$(".maincar__currency label").click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
    var selected = $('input[name=currency-is]:checked').val(); // <-- add this line
    $('.active_currency').text(selected.toUpperCase());  // <-- and this line
    alert(selected);
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $('.maincar__currency').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maincar__currency">
<div class="active_currency">EUR</div>
  <label for="euro-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__euro">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/euro.png" alt="Euro sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" value="euro" id="euro-radio-is" class="euro_radio_is" checked="true" />
            <span class="default">EUR</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="dollar-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__dollar">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/dollar.png" alt="Dollar sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="dollar-radio-is" class="dollar_radio_is" value="dollar" />
            <span>USD</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="gbp-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__pound">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/pound-sterling.png" alt="Pound sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="gbp-radio-is" class="gbp_radio_is" value="gbp" />
            <span>GBP</span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <label for="chf-radio-is">
        <div class="currency currency__chf">
            <img src="/assets/images/icons/swiss-franc.png" alt="Swiss franc sign">
            <input type="radio" name="currency-is" id="chf-radio-is" class="chf_radio_is" value="chf" />
            <span>CHF</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the first click is to show the other currencies. And then I need another click to choose the currency.

Comment: Thank you very much but I think my whole jQuery code messes the JS render that changes the values (But it's my fault because I didn't precise it in my question). Thnakyou anyway !